# How to remove latex tags using regex?

Tags: regex, latex, notepad++

I have to remove the bugging unnecessary tags in a document like:

```
{\sffamily FOOBARFOOOBAR
FOOBAR
FOO \bf{FOOBAR}
FOOBAR
}
```

into

```
FOOBARFOOOBAR
FOOBAR
FOO \bf{FOOBAR}
FOOBAR
```

I used to be able to do this with html tags like

{\sffamily \d } replacing with \1

but i cannot make it work with tex tags..

Anyone any advices?

Comment: You can't do this with regular expressions because nested tags are involved, unless you write a recursive regex (only supported in Perl, PHP and .NET), and even then you're probably better off with a parser. Notepad++ isn't going to cut it.

Comment: `\bf` in LaTeX is obsolete and deprecated. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516/does-it-matter-if-i-use-textit-or-it-bfseries-or-bf-etc

Answer (score 1):

I *can* give you a regex for your example - you weren't far off with your initial attempt - but I'm not sure it'll help with your overall problem.

Find:

```
\{\\sffamily ((?:.*\r*\n*)*?)\}
```

Replace:

```
\1
```

**WARNING:**
You will run into problems if the tags you're replacing are nested. But, I don't think there's going to be a way around that using regex without some serious headaches.
You would be better off with a small script here.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`detex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/detex), which strips TeX from a source file.

Comment: Would you happen to know a python package for this?