# regex in R to replace LaTeX tags

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to write a regex in R to replace LaTeX tags. Answers to [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236132/how-to-remove-latex-tags-using-regex) do not seem to work--is this because some rules are R-specific?

For example, where `rx` contains the regex pattern:

```
rx <- ""
gsub(rx, "", "lorum \begingroup ipsum")
```

I'd like for `gsub()` to return `lorum ipsum`.

What regex pattern could be used to do this?

Answer (score 2):

With `perl` enabled you can enclose literal characters to be replaced in `\Q...\E` (this tutorial helped to learn this: [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)). For your string you might use something like below. However, you might tune the regex a bit, depending on how your input string is actually read into R. Within R you can, e.g., not create the literal string `\end` since the backslash would mark the beginning of a special symbol, and there is no special symbol `\e`. This causes an error. Therefore, for the second part of the example string I had to use double escapes.

```
string = c("lorum \begin{group} ipsum", "lorum \\end{anothergroup} ipsum")
gsub("\\s(\begin|\\\\end)\\Q{\\E\\w+\\Q}\\E", "", string, perl = T)
# [1] "lorum ipsum" "lorum ipsum"
```

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, you can't do this easily in R because, since R lacks the concept of raw strings, you can't actually write `"lorum \begingroup ipsum"` without the backslash being parsed as a special character.

If you can replace each backslash with a double backslash, for example with a python script, then R would treat it as a single backslash and you could use:

```
gsub("\\\\[^[:space:]]*\\s", "", "lorum \\begingroup ipsum")
[1] "lorum ipsum"
```

But then you might as well just remove the whole tag in python or use a utility like [detex](https://ctan.org/pkg/detex) to do it.

I really hope that someone comes along with a better option and proves me wrong ...